# How to pass Python's keyword arguments with pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, embed, pybind11

Given this function: `__init__(username, password, **kwargs)` with these keyword arguments:

- auto_patch: Patch the api objects to match the public API. Default: False
- drop_incompat_key: Remove api object keys that is not in the public API. 
  Default: False
- timeout: Timeout interval in seconds. Default: 15
- api_url: Override the default api url base
- cookie: Saved cookie string from a previous session
- settings: A dict of settings from a previous session
- on_login: Callback after successful login
- proxy: Specify a proxy ex: ‘http://127.0.0.1:8888’ (ALPHA)
- proxy_handler: Specify your own proxy handler

I want to embed python in my C++ application with pybind11. **How do I pass the keyword arguments?** I am this far:

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h> // everything needed for embedding
#include <iostream>
namespace py = pybind11;

int main()
{
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{}; // start the interpreter and keep it alive

    py::module calc = py::module::import("calc");
    py::object result = calc.attr("__init__")("IGname", "IGpassword");

    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the right documentation: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/object.html

I cannot test it as I have some other issues occurring but that is the place to go.